# JOOQ + Spring Boot: как сгенерировать атрибуты?

Tags: java, spring, jooq

Итак, у меня JOOQ, Spring Boot и Maven.
Нашёл конфиг на гитхабе JOOQ. Адаптировал. В результате, получился такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>example</name>
    <description>Example</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <jooq.version>3.12.4</jooq.version>
        <spring.datasource.driver-class-name>org.postgresql.Driver</spring.datasource.driver-class-name>
        <spring.datasource.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example</spring.datasource.url>
        <spring.datasource.username>example_user</spring.datasource.username>
        <spring.datasource.password>example</spring.datasource.password>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-postgres</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdbc>
                                <driver>${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}</driver>
                                <url>${spring.datasource.url}</url>
                                <user>${spring.datasource.username}</user>
                                <password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>
                            </jdbc>
                            <generator>
                                <database>
                                    <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                                    <includes>.*</includes>
<!--                                    <excludes></excludes>-->
                                    <inputSchema>PUBLIC</inputSchema>
                                </database>
                                <generate>
                                    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                                    <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
                                    <pojos>true</pojos>
                                </generate>
                                <target>
                                    <packageName>ru.example.domain</packageName>
                                    <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                                </target>
                            </generator>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Вроде всё как указано в примере: `https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-boot-example`
При том, что никаких дополнительных конфигов не указано и что дальше делать, непонятно. По идее, при запуске приложения, плагин должен залезть в директорию `ru.example.domain` и наплодить в `target/generated-sources/jooq` атрибуты по сущностям, по которым он будет делать запросы. Вот пример сущности:

```
public class Profile {

    private Long id;
    private LocalDateTime created;
    private LocalDateTime updated;
    private ActiveType active = ActiveType.ENABLED;
    private Long userId;
    private Boolean agreedToDataProcessing;
    private Boolean agreedToTerms;
    private String fullName;
}
```

Генератор ничего не генерирует.
В других примерах, в частности, был настроен какой-то конфиг. На гитхабе JOOQ никакого конфига нет. Подскажите, что ещё нужно сделать для того, чтобы JOOQ таки нагенерировал мне атрибутов? Вполне подойдёт пример на гитхабе, с обязательными атрибутами Spring Boot + JOOQ + Maven.

Comment: Вячеслав, есть вопрос - чем не устроивает querydsl, который Spring поддерживает из коробки. Чем JOOQ лучше?

Comment: Меня устраивает, архитектора - нет.